# Reclassifying Rasters using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

Utilizing arcpy, I need to reclassify some rasters.  Once they're reclassified, I need to multiply all the rasters together and then clip them to a set feature. Can anyone assist?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env  
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = "C:\\Data"

outReclass1 = Reclassify("reclassstream", "Value",
                     RemapValue([1,0], [0,1]))
outReclass1.save("C:\\Data\\reclassStream1")

outReclass2 = Reclassify("pondbuffer", "Value",
                     RemapValue([1,0], [0,1]))
outReclass2.save("C:\\Data\\pondBuffer2")

outReclass4 = Reclassify("soilanalysis", "Value",
                     RemapValue([1,3,1], [3,6,2], [6,9,3], [9,12,4], [12,15,5]))
outReclass4.save("C:\\Data\\soilAnalysis4")




Raster1: reclassstream
Description: Streams with 150ft buffer
Reclassify Rules;
Current Value = 1 -----> New Value = 0
Current Value = NoData -----> New Value = 1

Raster2: pondbuffer
Description: Ponds with 200ft buffer
Reclassify Rules;
Current Value = 1 -----> New Value = 0
Current Value = NoData -----> New Value = 1

Raster3: PropertyUse
Description: Property Use Raster
Reclassify Rules;
No reclassification necessary

Raster4: soilanalysis
Description: Soil Analysis Raster
Reclassify Rules;
Current Value = 1-3 -----> New Value = 1
Current Value = 3-6 -----> New Value = 2
Current Value = 6-9 -----> New Value = 3
Current Value = 9-12 -----> New Value = 4
Current Value = 12-15 -----> New Value = 5
```

Comment: Do you have a spatial analyst license? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do have an .sa license.  I haven't tired anything yet.  I'm looking for a good start or insight

Comment: Read the documentation for IsNull https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000, Reclassify https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000 with RemapRange https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005m0000007m000000 that should be enough to get you started.